# Is implementation of method possible?

Tags: numerical-methods, matlab

Can I implement the Jacobi and Gauss-Seidel method,at a matrix, even if its determinant equals to zero?

I use Matlab and want to find the convergence of the method for the Hilbert matrix. I wanted to find its determinant and it equals to zero. Why is it like that? Isn't it wrong? Or shouldn't the determinant be nonzero to implement these methods?

Does it have to do with the precision of Matlab or is there anywhere else a problem?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hilbert_matrix (see closed form solution for the determinant). For Jacobi, if $\det(a) = 0$ then there is no unique solution., else there is a unique solution.

Comment: For a Hilbert Matrix 250x250,doesn't the determinant need to be non zero??Or am I wrong??Because,using matlab,I find it equal to zero.Is it right or has it to do with the precision that Matlab uses??

Comment: It is not zero. I calculated it with a CAS, but the number has a huge number of digits $1/(987221615027640...)$. This is using the symbolic form of the matrix, whereas your approach would suffer from numerical calculations. See if you can use the symbolic form and redo the calculations.

Comment: I haven't get taught how to use the symbolic form..Could you explain it to me??

Comment: http://www.mathworks.com/products/symbolic/. If that does not work, try another [*CAS*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_computer_algebra_systems).

Comment: I wrote this:det(vpa(hilb(250),15)) and got this:
 
ans =
 
(-9.4652078445025197746768251818616)*10^(-3875)

Comment: Is this right??

Comment: I have also to find the error:||x_{k}-S||,S accurate solution of linear system, of the last iteration and I get NaN.Has it to do with the determinant?What could I change,so I do not get NaN??

Comment: "The Hilbert matrices are canonical examples of ill-conditioned matrices, making them notoriously difficult to use in numerical computation." – "The Hilbert matrix is symmetric and positive definite." – from the Wikipedia page

Comment: So,is this right that I get NaN a result,when I calculate ||$x_{k}-S$||,or could I change something,for example the precision,so that I get a real number???

Comment: @evinda, I tried to give an answer, have a look. It would help if you could explain *why* you want to do this.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not an expert, but since nobody else is answering I'll give it a try. Feel free to correct me if I'm writing something wrong.

You are trying to numerically solve a linear system of equations, $A x = b$, where $A$ is a [Hilbert matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hilbert_matrix), using the Jacobi / Gauss-Seidel method(s). The [Jacobi method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jacobi_method) is guaranteed to converge if $A$ is diagonally dominant, which not the case for Hilbert matrices. The [Gauss–Seidel method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gauss%E2%80%93Seidel_method) is guaranteed to converge if $A$ is diagonally dominant *or* positive definite, and the latter is the case for Hilbert matrices, so in principle it should be possible to use the Gauss–Seidel method.

However, even though Hilbert matrices are positive definite, the determinant goes quickly to zero for increasing $n$, and the condition number grows as $\mathrm O ((1+\sqrt2)^{4n} / \sqrt n)$, so that for $n = 250$ it is of the order $10^{380}$. For larger $n$, Hilbert matrices are increasingly ill-conditioned, which means that numerical algorithms applied to them are increasingly unstable. Moreover, according to [this answer](https://mathoverflow.net/a/48140) on math overflow, the Gauss–Seidel method is not to be recommended as a numerical algorithm in itself.

This means that though in principle it should be possible to solve a linear system of equations defined by a Hilbert matrix using the Gauss–Seidel method, practically it is bound to fail, which is what you have experienced when you found that `det(hilb(250))` evaluates to 0 in Matlab due to limited numerical precision.

Comment: So,is this right that I found that the Gauss-Seidel method does not converge for any n,even if it is small,for example 50??
And something else..Could you tell me which is the spectral radius of a 50x50 Hilbert matrix,using Gauss-Seidel,so I can check my result?

Comment: Well it would converge if you had sufficiently high numerical precision; standard Matlab `double` precision is not enough. Even if you had arbitrary precision I'd expect it to converge very slowly.

Comment: Numerically, I get 2.07629668313116 for the largest eigenvalue of $H_{50}$.

Comment: So,is this wrong???And..are the settings difficult,one has to do to have higher precision?

Comment: Can I ask you again: *why* do you want to do this?